# How do I process data in a list in cold fusion 10

Tags: list, coldfusion

I have a form that has 3 rows. A checkbox and two input field per row.
The field names are paid, amount and tranid.
If I tick the checkbox on the second row, and enter data into the other two fields and click submit I have the following;

Listlen is 1.
listgetat(form.paid,1) contains the value assigned to the check box.
the list for amount are 0.00,16.00,0.00
The list for tranid id are "",Test123,"" (nul, value, nul)

Therein is my problem. I can't loop through the list because listlen = 1 and listgetat(form.amount,1) returns 0.00 because the data is in the second list item.

I can't get the value from listgetat(form.paid,2) because I only selected one checkbox, so listgetat(form.paid,1) contains that value.

Clearly my understanding of working with lists is lacking.

This is a payment processing page, where the user selects which outstanding payments have been paid. They enter a bank transaction ID and how much was paid. The number of rows depends on how many payments are outstanding, in this test case there are three.

Can someone please explain how to process the list.

thank you.

The input page; Select only unpaid transactions:

```
    <cfquery name="unpaid" datasource="#Application.datasource#">
    select * from payments where pflag=0
    </cfquery>
```

The input page; The three relevant fields;

```
    <cfif #unpaid.recordcount# gt 0>
            <cfoutput query="unpaid">
            <tr>
                <td><span class="pagetext">
                <input type="checkbox" name="paid" id="paid" value="#idpayments#" />                        
                </span></td>
            <td class="pagetext">#idpayments#</td>
                <input name="tranid" type="text" id="tranid" size="15" maxlength="40" /></td>
            <td align="right">
<span class="pagetext">$<input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" size="7" maxlength="7" value="#ap#" />                     
                </span></td>
            </tr>
            <cfset total=#total#+#ep#>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
```

> 

The processing code..

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#Listlen(FORM.amount)#" index="i">
    <cfif #ListGetAt(FORM.amount,i)# gt 0>
        <!--- update the payment --->
        <cfquery name="updtrec" datasource="#Application.datasource#">
            update payments set pflag=1,
            ap=#ListGetAt(FORM.amount,i)#,
            datepaid='#newdate#',
            <cfif #len(ListGetAt(FORM.tranid,i))# gt 0>,  ptranid=#ListGetAt(FORM.tranid,i)#</cfif>
            where idpayments=#ListGetAt(FORM.paid,i)#
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>A description of the issue is helpful, but you should also include some code along with it. The absolute *smallest* amount of code needed to illustrate the issue, omitting any irrelevant stuff like css. Here's a good example for this question:</s>

```
<form ...>
    Row #1
    <input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="111">
    Amount <input type="text" name="amount">
    TransId <input type="text" name="transid">
    <br>
    Row #2
    <input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="222">
    Amount <input type="text" name="amount">
    TransId <input type="text" name="transid">
    <br>
    Row #3
    <input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="333">
    Amount <input type="text" name="amount">
    TransId <input type="text" name="transid">
</form>
```

> Clearly my understanding of working with lists is lacking.

The problem isn't your understanding of lists, but of how form fields are handled. The code mistakenly assumes all three form variables will *always* contain a list of three values. They won't. While same `name`'d fields get converted into a comma separated list when submitted, not all form fields submit a value and some values are effectively discarded:

- A `checkbox` only submits a value IF it's checked
- An enabled `text` field always submits a value, but that value may be an empty string. Historically, most list functionality in CF *ignores* empty strings

So the `form` variables aren't guaranteed to *always* contain a list of three values. It may be less if some of the text fields are empty or boxes aren't checked (`form.paid` won't even exist at all if *none* of the boxes are checked). That's why the list functions aren't working as you expected.

Assuming you have a unique numeric value like an "id" for each row, give all checkboxes the same name and use the numeric id as the checkbox value. Then use the numeric "id" as part of the associated text field names, in order to group each row of fields together

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="111">
  <input type="text" name="amount_111">
  <input type="text" name="transid_111">
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="222">
  <input type="text" name="amount_222">
  <input type="text" name="transid_222">
  ...
```

When submitted, `form.paid` will contain a list of the selected id's. Loop through the list of id's and use the current "id" to extract the amount and transid values:

```
for (....) {
   amount = form["amount_"& currentId];
   transid = form["transid_"& currentId];
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Updated post with code.

Comment: Thanks.  Assuming `idpayments` is numeric and unique, then that would be your "id".

Comment: The number assigned to form.paid is numeric and unique. It is the row number on two tables (one is game details the other is payments). In this case the values for form.paid are 1465, 1466 and 1467 respectively. But sorry, I'm still not following. Is the _{id} added to the form element name literally as you've written it? And I don't understand what the loop will be?

Comment: Darn... I've just discovered another complexity. One transaction was only part paid. I need to cater for that. Back to the drawing board I think.

Comment: {Id} is whatever the current id is, like if the id is 1456, the fields would be "amount_1456", "tranid_1456". Also **never** use raw form values in a query, especially if it is dealing with payments, because it is an invitation to sql injection. Wrap all parameters in cfqueryparam.

Comment: I had to take the whole thing back to scratch. I hadn't catered for the possibilities of part payments, over payments or incorrect payments. Once I did that, the process changed completely and was easily solved using hidden fields. thanks for the assistance

Comment: Gotcha. Glad you worked it out. If you think it'd be helpful to others, feel free to post your final code as an answer.